# How to get id of clicked placemark on yandex maps?

Tags: javascript, typescript, yandex-api, yandex-maps

I've trying to get id of clicked placemark, but I can't find the way to do that.

I have the following code on TypeScript:

```
var map = new ymaps.Map( 'map', {
    center   : [55.76, 37.64],
    zoom     : 7
} );

var objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager( {} );
this.objectManager.events.add(['click'], function(event){

    // here i want to get placemark id

});
map.geoObjects.add( objectManager );

$.get( "/getObjects", {}, ( response:ServerResponse ) => {
    objectManager.add( data.objects );
}, "json" );
```

Here is the ServerResponse interface:

```
interface ServerResponse {
    status : string;
    count  : number;
    objects: {
        id      : number; // this is id, which I want to get
        type    : string;
        geometry: {
            type       : string;
            coordinates: string[]
        };
    }[]
}
```

So here is the question: how can i get id of placemark, which was clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this `var objectId = e.get('objectId');`?

You can see how to use ObjectManager in [YandexMap Sandbox](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_events) and in [ObjectManager Documentation](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager-docpage/).